# Debugging a rake task that is calling a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have the following rake task...

```
task :demote_sausages => :environment do
    session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
  puts "this is the demote sausages task"
  actions = UserAction.where action_date: Time.now.yesterday.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  actions.each do |a|
    session.post "/demote_sausage", {user_id: a.user_id}
  end
end
```

...and here is the controller action...

```
  def demote_sausage
    puts "made it to controller action"
    @z_options[:body][:id] = params[:user_id]
    @z_options[:body][:type] = 1
    HTTParty.post("https://api.blah.org/v1/user/update", @z_options)
  end
```

My issue is, I am not sure if I am making it to my controller action or not. I am seeing the puts message in the rake task, but I am NOT see the puts in the controller action (but maybe I shouldn't?).

Any tips on how to debug what is going on in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged it by assigning the session to a variable and then displaying it:

```
task :demote_sausages => :environment do
    session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
  puts "this is the demote sausages task"
  actions = UserAction.where action_date: Time.now.yesterday.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  actions.each do |a|
    var = session.post "/demote_sausage", {user_id: a.user_id}
    puts var.inspect
  end
end
```

Doing that I could see that that request was returning a 422 error code: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity Completed 422 Unprocessable. I am kind of confused as to why this error is being thrown. I thought 422 was when a request is being made from a domain other than where your app is running. In this case its all localhost. If someone has a good answer please add it as a comment.

Since I am doing a post request here I need to skip the check of the auth token. I did it like this...

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:demote_sausage]
```

...in my controller.